# How to copy a file to another path?

Tags: c#, file-io

I need to copy a file to another path, leaving the original where it is.

I also want to be able to rename the file.

Will FileInfo's CopyTo method work?

Comment: Do you wish to rename the original or the newly copied file?

Answer (score 97):

Have a look at [File.Copy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Using File.Copy you can specify the new file name as part of the destination string.

So something like

```
File.Copy(@"c:\test.txt", @"c:\test\foo.txt");
```

See also [How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Comment: And an important thing to note is that you can specify whether the destination file must be overwritten or not by adding the third argument as true or false.

Comment: It not suport for 2 server different

Comment: What is the purpose of the `@`?

Comment: @Alfie In C#, the sigil `@` is used to declare a verbatim string. Check [What is the difference between a regular string and a verbatim string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. It will work: [FileInfo.CopyTo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axsfwbc.aspx)

> Use this method to allow or prevent overwriting of an existing file. Use the CopyTo method to prevent overwriting of an existing file by default.

All other responses are correct, but since you asked for `FileInfo`, here's a sample:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\yourfile.ext");
fi.CopyTo(@"d:\anotherfile.ext", true); // existing file will be overwritten
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried to copy an xml file from one location to another. Here is my code:

```
public void SaveStockInfoToAnotherFile()
{
    string sourcePath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot";
    string destinationPath = @"G:\ProjectBO\ForFutureAnalysis";
    string sourceFileName = "startingStock.xml";
    string destinationFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".xml"; // Don't mind this. I did this because I needed to name the copied files with respect to time.
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, sourceFileName);
    string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, destinationFileName);

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
       {
         System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
       }
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
}
```

Then I called this function inside a timer_elapsed function of certain interval which I think you don't need to see. It worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `File.Copy` to copy and `File.Move` to rename it afterwords.

```
// Copy the file (specify true or false to overwrite or not overwrite the destination file if it exists.
File.Copy(mySourceFileAndPath, myDestinationFileAndPath, [true | false]);

// EDIT: as "astander" notes correctly, this step is not necessary, as File.Copy can rename already...
//       However, this code could be adapted to rename the original file after copying
// Rename the file if the destination file doesn't exist. Throw exception otherwise
//if (!File.Exists(myRenamedDestinationFileAndPath))
//    File.Move(myDestinationFileAndPath, myRenamedDestinationFileAndPath);
//else
//    throw new IOException("Failed to rename file after copying, because destination file exists!");
```

**EDIT**
Commented out the "rename" code, because `File.Copy` can already copy and rename in one step, as astander noted correctly in the comments.

However, the rename code could be adapted if the OP desired to rename the source file after it has been copied to a new location.

Comment: You do not have to copy and rename, you can do this in one step using File.Copy

Comment: Makes sense... I've done so much file renaming in code lately using File.Move that I didn't even think of File.Copy being able to rename, too :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationFileName);

// If directory doesn't exist create one
if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
{
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
}

File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

File::Copy will copy the file to the destination folder and File::Move can both move and rename a file.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to move a test file from the downloads to the desktop. 
I hope its useful.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Copy files to the desktop
    {
        string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\UsreName\Downloads";
        string targetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string[] shortcuts = {
            "FileCopyTest.txt"};

        try
        {
            listbox1.Items.Add("Starting: Copy shortcuts to dektop.");
            for (int i = 0; i < shortcuts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (shortcuts[i]!= null)
                {
                    File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, shortcuts[i]), Path.Combine(targetPath, shortcuts[i]), true);                        
                    listbox1.Items.Add(shortcuts[i] + " was moved to desktop!");
                }
                else
                {
                    listbox1.Items.Add("Shortcut " + shortcuts[i] + " Not found!");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            listbox1.Items.Add("Unable to Copy file. Error : " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TO Copy The Folder I Use Two Text Box To Know The Place Of Folder And Anther Text Box To Know What The Folder To Copy It And This Is The Code

```
MessageBox.Show("The File is Create in The Place Of The Programe If you Don't Write The Place Of copy And You write Only Name Of Folder");// It Is To Help The User TO Know
          if (Fromtb.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ples You Should Write All Text Box");
            Fromtb.Select();
            return;
        }
        else if (Nametb.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ples You Should Write The Third Text Box");
            Nametb.Select();
            return;
        }
        else if (Totb.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ples You Should Write The Second Text Box");
            Totb.Select();
            return;
        }

        string fileName = Nametb.Text;
        string sourcePath = @"" + Fromtb.Text;
        string targetPath = @"" + Totb.Text;


        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);


        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            //when The User Write The New Folder It Will Create 
            MessageBox.Show("The File is Create in "+" "+Totb.Text);
        }


        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);


        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);


            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);

            }
            MessageBox.Show("The File is copy To " + Totb.Text);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old Question,but I would like to add complete Console Application example, considering you have files and proper permissions for the given folder, here is the code

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //path of file
        string pathToOriginalFile = @"E:\C-sharp-IO\test.txt";

        
        //duplicate file path 
        string PathForDuplicateFile = @"E:\C-sharp-IO\testDuplicate.txt";
         
          //provide source and destination file paths
        File.Copy(pathToOriginalFile, PathForDuplicateFile);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Source: [File I/O in C# (Read, Write, Delete, Copy file using C#)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/file-io-in-c-read-write-delete-copy-file-using-c/114)

Answer (score -3):

```
File.Move(@"c:\filename", @"c:\filenamet\filename.txt");
```

Comment: "How to copy a file". You are moving it. Clearly not what the author asks for.

Comment: the answer you give is valid but not for the question I ask @mrblah