# how to copy war file progrmaticaly using c#

Tags: c#, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy a file to another path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979920/how-to-copy-a-file-to-another-path)

hi,

how to copy war files from one folder to another using c#.

Comment: Look up [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
DirectoryInfo sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("mySource");
FileInfo[] warFiles = sourceDirectory.GetFiles("*.war");

foreach(FileInfo file in warFiles)
{
    file.CopyTo("myDestination");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all. i got the solution using ur comments answers.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Easy
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destination)