# Read files from a Folder present in project

Tags: c#

I have a C# project (Windows Console Application).
I have created a folder named **Data** inside project. There are two text files inside folder Data.

How can I read the text files from "Data" folder.
I tried below things.

```
string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Names.txt")
```

It is thowing error that file not found.

I have checked some Stackoverflow answers posted before and none of then are working for me.

How can I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Google "current directory". The executable does not ncessarily run from your souce code folder!

Comment: Are you copying this data folder to the output when buildingthe project? Check the options on teh files and correct it.

Comment: the setting is Copy Always to output directory.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The code below should work:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Data\Names.txt");
string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Comment: My folder and files do not exist in the assembly folder :s .. Why is that?

Comment: in Visual Studio, mark the file and then set `Build Action` to `Content`, and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`

Comment: Just use @"Data\Name.txt" applying @FlorianMoser notation

Comment: what's that '@' means for?

Comment: @ there is called verbatim string literal, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string

Comment: To fully complete this thought, the '@' is there so you don't have to escape the backslask in the path.

Comment: I used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for the base path and it worked for unit testing as well.

Comment: The code in this answer should be used only if you have an intention to fetch the path like this:
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\e569ddac\c9182dba\assembly\dl3\e1c0b2a1\3fffb0d1_3b17d801\Data\Names.txt

Answer (score 41):

it depends where is your Data folder

To get the directory where the .exe file is:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

To get the current directory:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Then you can concatenate your directory path (`@"\Data\Names.txt"`)

Answer (score 24):

If you need to get all the files in the folder named 'Data', just code it as below

```
string[] Documents = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("../../Data/");
```

Now the 'Documents' consists of array of complete object name of two text files in the 'Data' folder 'Data'.

Comment: @Bunyip: do you need to read the contents of the text file or just to know the files in the folder?

Answer (score 19):

I have a C# project (Windows Console Application). I have created a folder named Images inside project. There is one ico file called MyIcon.ico. I accessed MyIcon.ico inside Images folder like below.

```
this.Icon = new Icon(@"../../Images/MyIcon.ico");
```

Answer (score 16):

Copy Always to output directory is set then try the following:

```
 Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
 String Root = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it is robust whether the file is in a library or in the executable project.

Comment: The main idea is that by setting copy always to output directory ,it always copies file/folder under bin folder and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns bin folder path.
For instance if you have Products.xlsx under ExcelSettings folder ,you get it with following:
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "ExcelSettings\\Products.xlsx)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's the only one that worked for me! OMG i've search so much, and so many duds..

Answer (score 1):

This was helpful for me, if you use the

```
var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

the path fill be beyond the current folder, it will incluide this path \bin\debug
What I recommend you, is that you can use the

```
string dir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName
```

then print the dir value and verify the path is giving you

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin.iOS you can use the following code to get contents of the file if file exists.

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "xyz.json");
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
var text =System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this Code for read all files in folder and sub-folders also

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        getfiles get = new getfiles();
        List<string> files =  get.GetAllFiles(@"D:\Document");

        foreach(string f in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        }


        Console.Read();
    }


}

class getfiles
{
    public List<string> GetAllFiles(string sDirt)
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sDirt))
            {
                files.Add(file);
            }
            foreach (string fl in Directory.GetDirectories(sDirt))
            {
                files.AddRange(GetAllFiles(fl));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }



        return files;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string myFile= File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"..\..\..\Data\myTxtFile.txt")
```

Comment: Please add some text detailing why this works/what it does

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21950637)