# c# handling paths -> System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()

Tags: c#, path, temp

IO.Path.GetTempFileName() in a c# application it's supposed to create a temp file and return the full path and filename, but the problem that i'm facing is that it ruturns the path with a double slash, just like this:

`C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp4230.tmp`

Is it correct? or should it return something like this:

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4230.tmp`

thanks in advance

Comment: If you're looking at the string in the debugger, it will "helpfully" show all the single backslashes as double backslashes. I suspect that's what's happening.

Comment: Those two paths look **exactly the same**.

Comment: Yeah, he's pasted it in wrong I assumed.

Comment: Visual studio will show double slashes with its intellisense, If you click the magnifying glass next to the path you are seeing you will see the exact string. (Deleted my answer as it resembled Matthews comment after edit)

Answer (score 1):

"\" is escape char having "\" in string require to mark it as verbatim or add double "\".

see [What is the difference between a regular string and a verbatim string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string)

Answer (score 0):

It's not, you're just looking in the wrong place. Try to write returned value to the file, you'll see there are no double slash