# Find and replace Asterisk (*) from a string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

> Durham * versus Yorkshire

and I have used a regex in C# to replace that asterisk in the string with some text, as:

```
string aString = "Durham * versus Yorkshire";
string newstring = Regex.Replace( aString, @"\*", "Replaced text");
```

I want this output:

> Durham Replaced Text versus Yorkshire

but this is not working. I thought that escaping the `*` with a `\` will find it. But its not. You can test it here as  well: [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com).
Can somebody tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Please put what you did in regex101.com. Do ctrl-s or command-s and share the link with us here.

Comment: Why not use `string.Replace`?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me, [Image](http://i.gyazo.com/781dbfdc86029c055a812bb3093d0e7c.png)

Comment: Tried with LinqPAD and works as expected

Comment: @sshashank124 here's the link: http://regex101.com/r/bP3kF5

Comment: why Regex for such a simple thing? `string newstring = aString .Replace("*", "Replaced text")`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - I need to this using regex for some reasons.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/qV1tE6

Comment: @Uriel_SVK I have put just a sample here. There is more to do. But the regex is not finding `*` anyway.

Comment: @sshashank124 thanks. But will this work in c#?

Comment: Your code seems to be working for everybody else. Can you show how you check the output? Also, if you *have* to use regex please update your example/explain more: as it is now you don't need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried your code and it seemed to work. Even your regex works on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/38q2k)

```
string aString = "Durham * versus * Yorkshire";
string newstring = Regex.Replace(aString, @"\*", "Replaced text");
```

Output

> Durham Replaced text versus Replaced text Yorkshire

You could also consider using String.Replace() like

```
aString.Replace("*", "Replaced text");
```

Comment: Damn! I was displaying the old string in the output field. Fixed it and now its working. My bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple replace like this one you don't need to use regex, [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will be enough:

```
string aString = "Durham * versus Yorkshire";
string newstring = aString.Replace("*", "Replaced text");
```

Comment: I need to do it using regex. I have told this above. Anyways I have marked the answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
string aString = "Durham * versus Yorkshire";
string newstring = Regex.Replace( aString, "\\*", "Replaced text");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string