# How to resolve newline character when sending an email using SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

```
string strTheBody = @"First Name: " + tbFirst.Text + "\nLast Name: " + tbLast.Text + "\nAddress 1: " + tbAdd1.Text + "\nAddress 2: " + tbAdd2.Text + "";
strTheBody += @"\nCity: " + tbCity.Text + "\nState: " + ddlTechState.SelectedValue + "\nZip Code: " + tbZip.Text + "\nDOB: " + tbDOB.Text + "\nEmail Address: " + tbEmail.Text + "";
strTheBody += @"\nLast Doctor visited: " + ddlTechProvider.SelectedValue + "\nIssue: " + ddlTechIssues.SelectedValue + "\n\nComments: " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(tbComments.Text) + "";

MailMessage mmSendEmail = new MailMessage();
mmSendEmail.To.Add("myemail@myweb.com");
mmSendEmail.From = new MailAddress(tbEmail.Text);
mmSendEmail.Subject = "Contacting about " + ddlTechIssues.SelectedValue;
mmSendEmail.Body = strTheBody;

SmtpClient scSend = new SmtpClient("mysmtp.myisp.com");
scSend.Send(mmSendEmail);
```

Sends the email like this:

```
First Name: first
Last Name: last
Address 1: my address 1
Address 2: \nCity: some city
State: NV
Zip Code: 90320
DOB: 08/08/2013
Email Address: myemail@email.com\nLast Doctor visited: 0
Issue: Result

Comments: This is a comment
```

How can I resolve the issue with the `\n` being displayed if the value is empty and when there is an email address.

Comment: They are displayed because you write them with verbatim string literal as `@"\nCity`. What do you mean by _resolve_ exactly? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: The `\n` should be a new line like the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @ symbol means to read that string literally, and don't interpret
>   control characters

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312007/3087342

I suggest using StringBuilder instead, will remove these type of errors and makes your code generally a lot more readable - in terms of formatting the email anyway.

Comment: Removed the `@` and it solved the problem. I will use StringBuilder as you mentioned because you are right, it is easier and more readeable. Thanks.

Comment: accept it answered @SearchForKnowledge bcoz #horHAY got the missing point. :)

Comment: I understand. I will when SO allows me to :)