# How to insert a query into another query in C# using Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, subquery

Is it possible to insert a query into another query in C#? Currently I am connecting to an access database and when I insert the query into another query in SQL view on Microsoft Access, the data I want is shown. However when I insert the same code into C#, the query is underlined. Basically this query is to include the data from the query produced in "Day" view to the FROM part in query for "Month" view.

How do I modify the query to be able to run in C#?

The query in SQL view on Microsoft Access for "Day view" is :

```
SELECT outbound.[Receipt date], outbound.[Receive plant], Avg(outbound.[Aging Days]) AS [AvgOfAging Days] FROM outbound GROUP BY outbound.[Receipt date], outbound.[Receive plant] HAVING (((outbound.[Receipt date]) Is Not Null));
```

The query in SQL view on Microsoft Access for "Month view" is:

```
SELECT Format([Receipt date],"mm/yyyy") AS [Month], Avg(Day.[AvgOfAging Days]) AS [AvgOfAvgOfAging Days] FROM  (SELECT outbound.[Receipt date], outbound.[Receive plant], Avg(outbound.[Aging Days]) AS [AvgOfAging Days] FROM outbound WHERE (outbound.[Receipt date] > #4/1/2015#) GROUP BY outbound.[Receipt date], outbound.[Receive plant] HAVING (((outbound.[Receipt date]) Is Not Null))) AS [Day] WHERE Day.[Receive plant] = "2300" GROUP BY Format([Receipt date],"mm/yyyy"), Day.[Receive plant] HAVING (((Format([Receipt date],"mm/yyyy")) Is Not Null));
```

(For the date and plant I have hard coded values to test the query but my actual program should read the user selection)

The code that has been modified to fit the C# application for "Month" view is:

```
string cmdQuery = "SELECT Format([Receipt date],\"mm/yyyy\") AS [Month], Avg(Day.[AvgOfAging Days]) AS [AvgOfAvgOfAging Days] "
                                + "FROM ("SELECT outbound.[Receipt date], outbound.[Receive plant], Avg(outbound.[Aging Days]) AS [AvgOfAging Days] " + "FROM outbound " + "WHERE ([Receipt date] >= #" + dateFrom + "#) AND ([Receipt date] <= #" + dateTo + "#) AND ((outbound.[Receive plant]) ='" + plant[i] + "')" + "GROUP BY outbound.[Receipt date], outbound.[Receive plant] " + "HAVING (((outbound.[Receipt date]) Is Not Null)); ) AS [Day] "

                                + "WHERE ((Day.[Receive plant]) ='" + plant[i] + "') "
                                + "GROUP BY Format([Receipt date],\"mm/yyyy\"), Day.[Receive plant] "
                                + "HAVING (((Format([Receipt date],\"mm/yyyy\")) Is Not Null)) ";
```

How do I edit the query above so that this query will be able to run in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Switch to parameterized values / placeholders (SQL Command Parameters); and then
2. Use `string.Format` to insert the sub-query, which should be a *valid* query by itself.

Simply add the inner parameters to the final SQL
Command object, along with any parameters for the outer query. That is to say, the string building is *only* for the query body and not for any data.

To make life easier the inner query should also be located in a derived-table location surrounded by parenthesis and given an alias name.

For example:

```
var innerQuery = "SELECT .. WHERE name = @name";
var finalQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM ({0}) AS T ..", innerQuery);

var cmd = conn.NewCommand();
cmd.CommandText = finalQuery;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Fred";
```

If this approach is followed then the only thing of concern is avoiding name clashes, which is easy if defining (and following) relevant rules.

---

Alternatively, use one of the many ORM/Mappers/LINQ providers that allow constructing queries, including embedded queries, in type-safe ways.

If continuing to write raw SQL in such a manner also consider using [verbatim string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work - but I would strongly suggest using a more maintainable way...

```
  string cmdQuery = "SELECT Format([Receipt date],\"mm/yyyy\") AS [Month], Avg(Day.[AvgOfAging Days]) AS [AvgOfAvgOfAging Days] "
                            + "FROM ( "+ "SELECT outbound.[Receipt date], outbound.[Receive plant], Avg(outbound.[Aging Days]) AS [AvgOfAging Days] " + "FROM outbound " + "WHERE ([Receipt date] >= #" + dateFrom + "#) AND ([Receipt date] <= #" + dateTo + "#) AND ((outbound.[Receive plant]) ='" + plant[i] + "')" + "GROUP BY outbound.[Receipt date], outbound.[Receive plant] " + "HAVING (((outbound.[Receipt date]) Is Not Null)); ) AS [Day] "

                            + "WHERE ((Day.[Receive plant]) ='" + plant[i] + "') "
                            + "GROUP BY Format([Receipt date],\"mm/yyyy\"), Day.[Receive plant] "
                            + "HAVING (((Format([Receipt date],\"mm/yyyy\")) Is Not Null)) ";
```

Comment: The above query is no longer underlined however, there seems to be a syntax error in the FROM clause when I run the application.

Comment: See answer by @user2864740 - what you have is too unmanageable.