# p.Start in C# errors

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, process, vb.net-to-c#

I've recently started to port a project to C# from VB, so I apologize if this is a noob-ish question. I can't seem to get this process to work for the life of me:

```
Process p = default(Process);
try
{
    p.Start("powershell", 
            "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -windowstyle hidden -file .\\scripts\Excel.ps1");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

I'm getting several errors:

> - Unrecognized escape sequence
> - Member Process.Start(string, string) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm moving from VB.net to C# because I prefer the syntax of C#, (coming from a java background) but I don't know a ton of C# visual studio workings.

EDIT2: Fixed the quotes with an @, still getting the

> - Member Process.Start(string, string) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

error.

Comment: [Verbatim strings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312007/107625) FTW.

Comment: `\\scripts\Excel.ps1` to `\\scripts\\Excel.ps1` ?

Comment: Side note: Catching and silently eating exception is an awful way of structuring your applications.

Comment: That fixes one problem, but I still have the "Member Process.start(string, string) error.

Comment: Isn't `default(Process)` equal to `null`?

Comment: Hi uwe, haven't got to the catch yet, just working on one thing at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the double slash in your Verbatim strings

```
p.Start("powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -windowstyle hidden -file .\\scripts\\Excel.ps1");
```

The other option is to use the @ symbol before it.

**For the second error:**

The error message says that: Member Process.Start(string, string) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead. So you need to call it like a `static method`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -windowstyle hidden -file .\\scripts\\Excel.ps1");
```

Comment: @Chostakovitch:- Typo. Updated!

Comment: Haha thats the one! Thanks for the help everyone! I'll mark the answer right once it lets me (3 more minutes remaining.)