# What is the difference between @ and \ operators in string?

Tags: c#, string, special-characters

There is `@` operator that you place infornt of the string to allow special characters in string and there is `\`. Well I am aware that with `@` you can use reserved names for variables, but I am curious just about difference using these two operators with string.

Search on the web indicated that these two are the same but I still believe there has to be something different between `@` and `\`.

Code to test:

```
string _string0 = @"Just a ""qoute""";
string _string1 = "Just a \"qoute\"";
Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}",_string0, _string1);
```

**Question:** what is the difference between `@"Just a ""qoute""";` and `"Just a \"qoute\"";` only regarding strings?

**Edit:** Question is already answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string

Comment: So basically no difference in substance, only in representation in the source.  Once compiled they are identical.

Answer (score 2):

Using @ (which denotes a *verbatim string literal*) you can put any character into the string, even line breaks. The only character you need to escape is the double quote. The usual `\*` escape sequences and Unicode escape sequences are not processed in such string literals.
Without @ (in a *regular string literal*), you need to escape every special character, such as line breaks.

You can read more about it at the C# Programming Guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx#Anchor_3

Answer (score 1):

@ is a verbatim string, it allows you not to escape every special character at a time, but all of them in the string.While \ just allows you to escape one certain character.
More info about strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx