# Add double quotes to the datatable column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

In one of my `datatable` column, I want the value to be shown in **double quotes**

AS:-  `"My value"`

Below is my code:-

```
 string StrPriBody = "Dear User, <br><br> The Number of days revised by you from " +
     " " + table.Rows[0]["LAST_ACTION_DAYS"] + " days to " +
     " " + table.Rows[0]["CURRENT_ACTION_DAYS"] + " days. <br /> " +
     " with Remark <b> " + table.Rows[0]["REMARKS"] + "</b><br /><br />";
```

> I want to show REMARK value in double quotes.

How to achieve that ?

Comment: You can use escape sequence to display double quote. Use \" within string

Comment: @PiyushKhatri: can you show it with some code, so that I can get an idea of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extra quotes with backslash:

```
string StrPriBody = "Dear User, <br><br> The Number of days revised by you from " +
     " " + table.Rows[0]["LAST_ACTION_DAYS"] + " days to " +
     " " + table.Rows[0]["CURRENT_ACTION_DAYS"] + " days. <br /> " +
     " with Remark <b> \"" + table.Rows[0]["REMARKS"] + "\"</b><br /><br />";
```

Comment: It just ignores the next character.

Answer (score 1):

Use \ to print the escape sequence characters in a string

```
 " with Remark <b> \"" + table.Rows[0]["REMARKS"] + "\" </b><br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

For better readability I would use [verbatim string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string), as it allows to avoid concatenation and easily expand on multiple lines. Also, `String.Format` would make your string more readable:

```
string StrPriBody = String.Format(@"
Dear User, 
<br><br> 
The Number of days revised by you from {0} days to {1} days. <br />
with Remark <b> ""{2}""</b>
<br /><br />",
   table.Rows[0]["LAST_ACTION_DAYS"],
   table.Rows[0]["CURRENT_ACTION_DAYS"],
   table.Rows[0]["REMARKS"]);
```

Also, C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015) has introduced [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx), that makes string construction even more reader friendly:

```
string StrPriBody = $@"
Dear User, 
<br><br> 
The Number of days revised by you from {table.Rows[0]["LAST_ACTION_DAYS"]} days to {table.Rows[0]["CURRENT_ACTION_DAYS"]} days. <br />
with Remark <b> ""{table.Rows[0]["REMARKS"]}""</b>
<br /><br />";
```