# Using string.Join with Tab Delimiter?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to use string.Join to create a tab-delimited string and output that into a file?

I'm doing this:

```
string.Join(@"\t", array);
```

But in my file (I've tried .txt and .csv), the results are as such:

```
one\ttwo\tthree\tfour\tfive
```

I assume it's because the delimiter isn't a standard one-character delimiter because it works perfectly fine using pipes or commas.

I know there are many other ways this can be done but I was hoping to create a one-size-fits-all solution using string.Join which may just not be possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the verbatim character literal @

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using verbatim string @"\t" instead of a regular string. Use "\t".

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string) for reference.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. I completely misread another SO users post saying not to use the @! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same problem and `string.Join("\t", array)` didn't work for me.

`string.Join(Constants.vbTab, array)` did the job for me.