# How to pass a string which contains HTML to an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, onclick

I'm creating an  element in my c# code, which contains a onclick event that copies the string parameter to the clipboard.

It works fine, the problem is when I have to pass an parameter that is a HTML code, with 
 and  tags. It breaks my page, because of the quotes (') that may appear (like style and colspan tags).

The code I'm using is this:

```
string comment = row.Cells[1].Text;

Cells[0].Text += "<br/><a href='javascript:' onclick='javascript:CopyComment(" + comment + ")'>COPY</a>";
```

How can I pass a string with HTML as parameter and not break my page?

EDIT 1:

This is the HTML Code I'm passing as parameter:

```
> "<span style='color:#FF0000;'><b>COTAÇÃO</b></span><br />\r\n<br
> />\r\n<br />\r\nAssunto: Cotação / Assistência: 425595 / Placa:
> EAL8426<br />\r\n<br />\r\nSegue conforme solicitado:<br />\r\n<br
> />\r\n<span
> style='text-decoration:underline;'><b>ORIGEM:</b></span><br />\r\nRua
> Glauber Rocha, 39 - Jardim Alzira, São Paulo - SP, 03986-270, Brasil,
> 39<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<span
> style='text-decoration:underline;'><b>DESTINO:</b></span><br />\r\nR.
> Conselheiro Saraiva, 36 - Santana, São Paulo - SP, Brasil, 36<br
> />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<b>Cotação 1</b><br />\r\nTempo de Chegada:
> 50<br />\r\n<br
> />\r\n<table>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>Tarifa</td><td>Valor</td><td>Quantidade</td><td>Total</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>Saída</td><td>R$
> 99,00</td><td>1</td><td>R$ 99,00</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>KM
> (Excedente)</td><td>R$ 1,50</td><td>10</td><td>R$
> 15,00</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>Pedágio</td><td>R$
> 20,00</td><td>1</td><td>R$ 20,00</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>Horas
> Trabalhadas</td><td>R$ 46,00</td><td>2</td><td>R$
> 92,00</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>KM (Deslocamento)</td><td>R$
> 1,50</td><td>10</td><td>R$
> 15,00</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>Destombamento</td><td>R$
> 125,00</td><td>1</td><td>R$ 125,00</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td
> colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td><td>Total</td><td>366,00</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</table>\r\n<br
> />\r\n\r\n<br />\r\nNo aguardo<br />\r\n<br />\r\nAtenciosamente\r\n"
```

this is my javascript function that copies the text (with the HTML format) to the clipboard

```
function CopiarComentario(html) {
    var tmpEl;
    tmpEl = document.createElement("div");

    // since we remove the element immediately we'd actually not have to style it - but IE 11 prompts us to confirm the clipboard interaction and until you click the confirm button, the element would show. so: still extra stuff for IE, as usual.
    tmpEl.style.opacity = 0;
    tmpEl.style.position = "absolute";
    tmpEl.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    tmpEl.style.zIndex = -1;

    // fill it with your HTML
    tmpEl.innerHTML = decodeHtml(html);

    // append the temporary node to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(tmpEl);

    // select the newly added node
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(tmpEl);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    // copy
    document.execCommand("copy");

    // and remove the element immediately
    document.body.removeChild(tmpEl);
}

function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a [verbatim sting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312007/4416750)?

Answer (score 1):

```
Cells[0].Text += "<br/><a href='javascript:' onclick='javascript:CopyComment(" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(comment) + ")'>COPY</a>";
```

[Read more about HttpUtility.HtmlEncode here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My javascript function that copies to clipboard needs an HTML code, so it keeps the format in case of the person wants to put the text into an email, for example.

Comment: You need to decode HTML inside your CopyComment function. Here is an example of how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it

Comment: Never thought to decode on the client side.

But now I get this error when i click: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

But there's no '}' on my code.

Comment: I'm afraid I need to see the code to help with that.