# code optimisation : list loop and query c# sql server compact edition

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce-4

the code here is for checking is there any interaction between added drugs in a dataGridView ( Productgridview )

- front end : C# with VS2012 .Net 4.0
- back end : sql server compact edition 4.0

**the schema for database :**

- table product : productId ; name
- table product_druginteractionclass : productId ;
  druginteractionclassId
- table interaction : interactionId ; druginteractionclassId1 ;
  druginteractionclassId2 ; riskcomment
- table druginteractionclass : druginteractionclassId ; name

many products can have same drug interaction class number

**the approach is :**

- looping throw **Productgridview** to retrieve the **productid** based on **name**
  and select **druginteractionclassId** based on **productid** then put the result in another  dataGridView (**listclassification**)
- create 2 lists from data in column druginteractionclassId from  dataGridView (**listclassification**)  /// a minor problem is here it show interaction between same drug because the lists hold same all druginterctionclass number and double iterating throw them to test combination interactions /// **how to create separate lists programmatically while i can not know how much drugs will be added ?**
- looping throw 2 lists and select interactions based on combinations and join the result with a drug interaction class name

**is it possible to create lists dynamically and looping throw them to
       do combinations while not know how much lists till run time ?**

**i think of also  looping inside the interaction gridview and check if a products is repeated if no remove the inappropriate interaction .**

- **may be all off that can be summarized in a one query , how to wrote
  one  (that kind of select of select of select)?**

actually i am pharmacy student ( i just like to code and do not do it well,  i do not even complete any c# book just around 600 page between c# / sql / ado.net so excuse me  )

```
        var ds2 = new DataSet();
        for (var i = 0; i < Productgridview.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var listclasse = Productgridview.Rows[i].Cells["Productid"].Value.ToString();
            var datadrug2 = "SELECT *  FROM product_druginteractionclass" +
                            " where productId = '" +
                            listclasse + "'"; // listclasse is the list of  manually added drugClass
            var connection1 = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

            var dataadapter1 = new SqlCeDataAdapter(datadrug2, connection1);
            //var ds = new DataSet();
            connection1.Open();
            dataadapter1.Fill(ds2, "product_druginteractionclass");
            connection1.Close();
        }
        listclassification.DataSource = ds2;
        listclassification.DataMember = "product_druginteractionclass";

/////////////// put the druginteractionclass into 2 lists 
        var list1 = new List<string>();
        var list2 = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in listclassification.Rows)
            if ((item.Cells.Count >= 2) && //atleast two columns
                (item.Cells[1].Value != null)) //value is not null
            {
                list1.Add(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                list2.Add(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }
        //for (var i = 0; i <= list.Count - 1; i++)
        //{
        //   // MessageBox.Show(list[i].ToString());
        //}

        //////////// select interaction based on druginteractionclass
        var ds = new DataSet();
        for (var i = 0; i <= list1.Count - 1; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j <= list2.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                var value = list1[i];
                var value1 = list2[j];
                var datadrug3 = "SELECT u1.name, u2.name  , m.* " +
                                "FROM druginteractionclass u1 " +
                                "left outer JOIN interaction m" +
                                " ON u1.druginteractionclassId = m.druginteractionclassId1 " +
                                "left outer JOIN druginteractionclass u2 " +
                                "ON u2.druginteractionclassId = m.druginteractionclassId2" +
                                " where m.druginteractionclassId1 = '" + value +
                                "' and m.druginteractionclassId2 ='" + value1 + "'" +
                                "Order by m.severity ";

                var connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

                var dataadapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(datadrug3, connection);

                connection.Open();
                dataadapter.Fill(ds, "interaction");
                connection.Close();
            }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "interaction";

        /////// remove duplicated interactions  
        for (var currentRow = 0; currentRow < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; currentRow++)
        {
            var rowToCompare = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow];

            for (var otherRow = currentRow + 1; otherRow < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; otherRow++)
            {
                var row = dataGridView1.Rows[otherRow];

                var duplicateRow = true;

                for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                    if (!rowToCompare.Cells[2].Value.Equals(row.Cells[2].Value))
                    {
                        duplicateRow = false;
                        break;
                    }

                if (duplicateRow)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
                    otherRow--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                        var datadrug3 =
                        @" SELECT m.interactionId , u1.name , n.name , u2.name,n2.name   , m.riskComment , m.precautionComment , m.severity 

                         FROM druginteractionclass u1 
                         left outer JOIN interaction m 
                         ON u1.druginteractionclassId = m.druginteractionclassId1 
                         left outer JOIN druginteractionclass u2 
                         ON u2.druginteractionclassId = m.druginteractionclassId2 

                         left outer join product_druginteractionclass p1 
                         ON  p1.druginteractionclassId = m.druginteractionclassId1 

                         left outer JOIN product_druginteractionclass p2 
                         ON  p2.druginteractionclassId = m.druginteractionclassId2 

                         left outer join product n 
                         ON  n.productId= p1.productId 

                         left outer join product n2 
                         ON n2.productId= p2.productId 
                         where n.productId = @value  and n2.productId = @value1 ";

                    var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString3);
                    var com = new SQLiteCommand(datadrug3, connection);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1",value1 );
                        var dataadapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(com);

                    connection.Open();
                    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "interaction");
                    connection.Close();
```

Comment: Consider using a [verbatim string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312075/3276027) instead of concatenating strings (very error prone) and use sqlParameters

Comment: thanks Gian Paolo ,  verbatim  string help parsing query very well and from different breakpoints  i notice that /// dataadapter.Fill(ds, "interaction");////  is taking a long time ,  i test the query in SQL Compact Query Analyzer an exception has been thrown ( out of memory ) i conclude that the engine of sql server compact reach his limits ( sql server 2014 do it so fast with condition "where" no freeze in application and without condition he do 3.5 million row in 2 minutes  )

Comment: actually, verbatim string should just improve code readability, and not performance: concatenating string with + will not take any appreciable time. 
At opposite, using SQLParameters instead of concatenating the value of parameter will improve SQL server performance: sql server will "compile" the query the first time it is executed and then it will use a cached compiled version of it.

Comment: @ Gian Paolo , i do it with parameters and SqlCe render the results but very slow ; i changed to sqlite it is better ( about 13s to test one combination ) ; i know now it is the engine who can not hundle the query could you please suggest another query ( this query in sql server 2014 without the condition where result 17 million row in 14 min and the 3 last left join has the higher cost )