# C# regex not matching my string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex string:

```
string regex =
                "\"\\d*\",\"(?<url>\\w|\\d|[().,-–_'])\".*";
```

And a string I want to match it against:

```
string line =
   "\"4\",\"1800_in_sports\",\"24987709\",\"\",\"1906\",\"20171028152258\"";
```

When I try to get the url category, or even check for a match, there is no match:

```
var result = Regex.Match(line, regex);
string output = result.Groups["url"].Value;
```

If i try Regex.IsMatch(..) it also returns false.
I used http://regexstorm.net/tester to test this and **it works there**, but, not when I run the code.

In RegexStorm I used the pattern:

```
"\d{1,3}","(?<url>\w|\d|\n|[().,-–_'])+?"
```

Comment: Please use [verbatim strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/) and tell us the expression you used in RegexStorm..

Comment: Okay I didn't realize you could use double quotes in a verbatim string, I will try that. Thanks. 
I also edited the question to include the pattern I used in RegexStorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Dour High Arch mentioned, verbatim string should be used. Adding double quotes in front of double quotes allows for verbatim strings.

Changing string regex to:

```
string regex =
                @"""\d{1,3}"",""(?<url>\w|\d|\n|[().,-–_''])+?""";
```

Now returns a match.

Answer (score 0):

Replace \\d with just \d and \\w with just \w.

Comment: This will not compile due to "unrecognized escape sequence". If I add $ to the beginning of the string I cannot add \".

Comment: \d says match a digit, \\d says match "\d", You want the former not the latter.

Comment: When the string is read with Regex it sees "\d" not "\\d". For example, 
    string regex = "\"\\d*\""; would work.