# Get string between / and \ using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Please consider this string:

```
http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData\
```

I want to get `GetData` using regular expression. I test it with this code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\/\\w*\\");
```

But I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'parsing "/\w*\" - Illegal \ at end of pattern.'

and then I test this code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\/\w*\\");
```

but it doesn't work and doesn't recognize any match.

Hot I can recognize `GetData` in above string using regular expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData\";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/(\w*)\\");
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    //  data = "GetData"
    var data = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

`Regex("\\/\\w*\\")` after backslashes escaping results to regular expression `\/\w*\` . This expression is incorrect because of tailing backslash. That causes `Illegal \ at end of pattern` error.

With so many backslashes that should be escaped in RE, there is a big chance to make a mistake. This is a reason why it's better to use [verbatim strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string) when you build regular expression. The same regular expression with usual C# string should be built as `new Regex("/(\\w*)\\\\$")`. Those four slashes at the end are just killing me.

Comment: Thanks but your pattern does not recognize `GetData` in `var input3 = "\"http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData\"";`

Comment: If backslash could be not the last character of the input string, then you should just remove `$` from my original regular expression. I've edited the answer.