# How to match exactly one or more characters inside boundary

Tags: c#, regex

Currently i using this pattern: `[HelloWorld]{1,}`.
So if my input is: Hello -> It will be match.
But if my input is WorldHello  -> Still match but not right.
So how to make input string must match exactly will value inside pattern?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the square brackets, and the comma and you're good to go!

```
HelloWorld{1}
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex what's between square brackets is a character set.

So `[HelloWorld]` matches 1 character that's in the set `[edlorHW]`.
And `.{1,}` or `.+` both match 1 or more characters.

What you probably want is the literal word.
So the regex would simple be `"HelloWorld"`.
That would match HelloWord in the string "blaHelloWorldbla".

If you want the word to be a single word, and not part of a word? 
Then you could use wordboundaries `\b`, which indicate the transition between a word character (`\w = [A-Za-z0-9_]`) and a non-word character (`\W = [^A-Za-z0-9_]`) or the beginning of a line `^` or the end of a line `$`.

For example `@"\bHelloWorld\b"` to get a match from "bla HelloWorld bla" but not from "blaHelloWorldbla".

Note that the regex string this time was proceeded by `@`.
Because by [using a verbatim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string) the backslashes don't have to be backslashed.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you need to use online regex tester web sites to check your pattern. for example you could find one of them [here](http://regexstorm.net/)  and also you could study c# regex reference [here](http://regexstorm.net/reference)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this pattern:**

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,}
```

You can test it [online](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

[image]