# How handle apostrophe in filter expression?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

Given some json:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "Bill's Automotive",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to return the **Bill's Automotive** phone number object:

```
{
  "type"  : "Bill's Automotive",
  "number": "0123-4567-8888"
}
```

Using Json.NET, which uses the [jsonpath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) syntax, i have the filter expression:

```
phoneNumbers.[?(@.type=="Bill's Automotive")]
```

And this works fine when you test it on:

- https://jsonpath.com/

where you can try this for yourself.

## But fails in Json.net

But in C#, at runtime, using Newtonsoft Json.Net, the code throws an exception:

```
JToken billsPhone= o.SelectToken("phoneNumbers.[?(@.type=="Bill's Automotive")]");

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: Unexpected character while parsing path query: s
```

Obviously it sees the apostrophe, and thinks its the end of the query string.

**Other variations i have tried**

- `phoneNumbers.[?(@.type=="Bill's Automotive")]`
- `phoneNumbers.[?(@.type=="Bill\'s Automotive")]`
- `phoneNumbers.[?(@.type=="Bill''s Automotive")]`
- `phoneNumbers.[?(@.type=="Bill\u0027s Automotive")]`

So i give up.

**How do you filter json in Newtonsoft Json.NET?**

Comment: Should be trivial using Linq-To-Objects.  Would that be an option, rather than jsonpath?

Comment: Escape the double-quote, not the single-quote.

Comment: Escape character: \'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide backslash-escaped quote to the query:

```
JToken billsPhone = o.SelectToken("phoneNumbers.[?(@.type=='Bill\\'s Automotive')]");
```

Note that you need single quotes to wrap search term and `\\` so final string actually contains `\'`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I don't know how to do it with `SelectToken`, but</s> See Alexei's answer for escaping the quote, but you can do it with some [LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm#SelectTokenLINQ).

```
 var billsPhone = o["phoneNumbers"]
                  .FirstOrDefault(t => t["type"].Value<string>() == "Bill's Automotive");
```

Answer (score -1):

[Use a verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

```
JToken billsPhone = o.SelectToken(@"phoneNumbers.[?(@.type==""Bill's Automotive"")]");
```

[What is the difference between a regular string and a verbatim string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string)

[Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Comment: What version of Newtonsoft Json.Net you are using? The code you shown does not seem to work with current (12.x) one claiming `"` is unexpected... I mean it indeed compile unlike sample shown in the question... But does not work earlier than OP said - so most likely code in the question is not 100% one OP tried (but close enough).