# Declaring a long string of VBA in C#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

I have a long string of text with very specific indents, specifically text for a VBA run.

I was wondering how to turn it into a string for declaring using this:

```
Clipboard.SetText(string);
```

I've seen people using it as a text file, adding it in resources, but I'm not sure about any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [verbatim-string](/questions/tagged/verbatim-string)

```
string s = @"Verbatim string
    with indentation
        embedded new line
            and special characters: C:\myfolder\myfile.txt
                You can embed things like VBA source code like this
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
    If a = b
        ' Do something
    End If
End Sub";

Console.WriteLine(s);
Clipboard.SetText(s);
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NAjoNM)

When a string is prepended with `@` all special escapes will be disabled. Now you can have embedded new lines and backslashes inside the string. The only downside is that you have to escape a double quote with 2 double quotes

```
string t = @"""C:\Windows\System32"" is the system folder"
```

so it's less convenient that C++ [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) or [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in many other languages, but it's still better than escaping or concatenating everything

- [Strings (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)
- [@ (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)
- [What is the difference between a regular string and a verbatim string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3311988/995714)

Comment: I made a text file containing the VBA code and put it in the resources folder as string called ExcelVBA. I plan on exporting a desktop app and have the code be universal with anyone who uses the app, so what would the best approach if I wanted to use that without having a long string to intent on the code.