# Encode only word test in \"test"\ with regex?

Tags: c#

I want to only encode a substring in my string, here `test` from `String str = \"test"\`

Is there a better way to do this than what I did below? Perhaps through an regEx?

```
var fullStr = "\"\\test\"\\";
char[] charsToTrim = { '\"', '\\'};
string result = fullStr.Trim(charsToTrim);
string StrEncoded =  Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));

string retStr = "\"\\" + StrEncoded + "\"\\";
```

Comment: why don't use a [verbatim string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3311988/995714) to make it more readable: `@"""\test""\"`, `@"""\"`, `@"""\"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for this regex

`(?<="\\).*?(?="\\)`

`(?<="\\)` - > Positive lookbehind (check if there are these characters behind you)
`(?="\\)` - > Positive lookahead (check if there are these characters ahead of you)

`.*` -> Select everything in between

The new code:

```
        var fullStr = "\"\\test\"\\";
        char[] charsToTrim = { '\"', '\\'};
        string result = fullStr.Trim(charsToTrim);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        string pattern = "(?<=\"\\\\).*?(?=\"\\\\)";
        var m = Regex.Match(fullStr, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

And [dotnet fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bLd84X)

My guess is you are looking for the following:

```
string pattern = "(?<=\"\\\\).*?(?=\\\\\")";
```

Comment: You may want to use `.*?` instead of `.*` as the latter will match everything from the first quote to the last in the input (greedy) which is probably wrong if the input contains multiple "..." parts.

Comment: Good thinking Klaus, I'll update the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.Match()` with a `MatchEvaluator`.

```
...
string retStr = Regex.Replace(fullStr, "test", delegate (Match match)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(match.Value));
});
...
```