# Command to copy a file to another, user-chosen directory?

Tags: c#, file

I have this code to copy a file to another destination, however I need the users to choose the destination plus the name of file copied is = the old name with the date and hour of my PC ..

```
string fileToCopy = @"d:\pst\2015.pst";
string destinationDirectoryTemplate = textBox2.Text;

var dirPath = String.Format(destinationDirectoryTemplate, DateTime.UtcNow);
var di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

if (!di.Exists)
{
    di.Create();
}

var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileToCopy);
var targetFilePath = Path.Combine(dirPath, fileName);

File.Copy(fileToCopy, targetFilePath);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to fix **image** with bad code formatting.

Comment: Please copy/paste the code into your post (so other people can paste it into their own editor to make changes), and describe what is happening when you try to run this.

Comment: string fileToCopy = @"d:\pst\2015.pst";
            string destinationDirectoryTemplate = textBox2.Text;
                    var dirPath = string.Format(destinationDirectoryTemplate, DateTime.UtcNow);
                    var di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
                    if(!di.Exists)
                        {
                            di.Create();
                        }
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileToCopy);
                    var targetFilePath = Path.Combine(dirPath, fileName);
            File.Copy(fileToCopy, targetFilePath);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file to another path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979920/how-to-copy-a-file-to-another-path)

Comment: no i need string destinationDirectoryTemplate  got his full path in textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileToCopy = @"e:\TestFile.pdf"; 
            string destinationDirectoryTemplate = TextBox1.Text;
            var dirPath = string.Format(destinationDirectoryTemplate, DateTime.UtcNow);
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
            if (!di.Exists) 
            { di.Create(); } 
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileToCopy);
            var extn = Path.GetExtension(fileToCopy);

            var finalname = fileName + " " + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now) + extn;
            var targetFilePath = Path.Combine(dirPath, finalname);
            File.Copy(fileToCopy, targetFilePath);
        }
```