# Create file while running C# using template file which is added in the project

Tags: c#, .net

Have added a text file in my C# project and it contains static value (around 300 lines). Will it possible to create a txt in specified path and file name using template file content which is attached in the project. When ever the binary runs it has to create a txt in the specified path with the content available in the template file.

[image]

Comment: yes you can.. post some codes that you tried to get better solutions

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979920/how-to-copy-a-file-to-another-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps:

**1)** Add your template file to project as Embedded Resource.

Click on `QAXXXXVBSFile.txt` in Solution Explorer and set `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`

[Embedded Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAyY2.png)

**2)** Read this resource by using `GetManifestResourceStream()` and write data in the new text file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AutomateDigicall
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get current assembly
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceName = "AutomateDigicall.QAXXXXVBSFile.txt";

            string template = String.Empty;

            // Read resource from assembly
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                template = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            // Write data in the new text file
            var filePath = "C:\\TestFolder\\myFileName.txt";
            using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Text from template below:");
                writer.WriteLine(template);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is probably to add the file as a Project Resource.  Right click on your C# project and select Properties, then Resources.  Click the link to add a Resources file if prompted, then select the option to add your file as a Proejct Resource.  You can then access the file content in your C# code via `[Project Namespace].Properties.[File Name]`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.