# saveFileDialog-Image: Select image and then save it in another folder

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I'm creating an application and I want to create a label which when clicked, will open an "openFileDialog", the user will select a .jpg or .png image, and then this selected image will be copied to a predefined directory (specific folder).

For now, I have a separate label-button which when clicked, opens an "openFileDialog" and the selected picture is then shown in a pictureBox. 
What I do not know, is how to grab this selected picture, and copy it in the predfined directory.

I would also like to somehow rename it when copying it to the directory, so I can later short the pictures by date added and display them through another label-button.

Here is the code I have, for the very first button:

```
private void addlabel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Image File;
        OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
        f.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.png) | *.jpg; *.png";

        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            File = Image.FromFile(f.FileName);
            pictureBox3.Image = File;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to *grab the selected image*? You have the filename (in `f.FileName`), which you clearly know because you use it. So you have the filename you need to copy the file whether you load the file into a picturebox or not. So do some research on *how to copy a file in C#*. You can rename it to whatever you want while copying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file to another path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979920/how-to-copy-a-file-to-another-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pictureBox3.Image.Save(specific_folder + "\\" + f.SafeFileName);
```

as follow:

```
private void addlabel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Image File;
    OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
    f.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.png) | *.jpg; *.png";

    if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File = Image.FromFile(f.FileName);
        pictureBox3.Image = File;
        pictureBox3.Image.Save(specific_folder + "\\" + f.SafeFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response! This will get the image from the pictureBox3 and save it to the specific_folder, right ? Not copy it from its original path, if I'm correct. One more thing, what does the f.SafeFileName do exactly? Thanks!

Comment: `SafeFileName` returns a string that only contains the file name for the selected file not full path.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
    if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File = Image.FromFile(f.FileName);
        pictureBox3.Image = File;
        File.Copy(f.FileName, @"C:\MyDestination\" + f.SafeFileName;
    }
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx